# SQL Reporting Services move subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I do have a general question about the MS SQL Reporting Service 2008:
Is it possible to move existing Subscriptions from one Reporting Server to a new one without moving the complete Reporting Service and Temp DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to move existing Subscriptions from one Reporting Server to a new one you need to move both the databases; the reportservertempdb database and reportserver database.